# Facebook Graph gets all events that a user has been invited to

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I get all events that a user has been invited to or rsvp'd to?
I've tried doing a request to `/me/events` and `/me/events/not_replied` but I just get empty responses back.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was "noreply", not "not_replied", and it is not available anymore: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#events-4-4

In order not to break any existing Apps (not dealing with errors), you don´t get an error, but just an empty response.

Comment: you are welcome, but please do not forget to accept my answer.